# ActionScript not showing up in Actions - Frame window in Flash CS5

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

In an existing fla file, I'm not able to find strings within actionscript that is contained within certain frames (regardless of which frame it's in). So for example in frame 1 there is the following code:

```
stop();
```

But searching for 'stop' (without quotes) doesn't turn up any results.

If I create a new fla file, I'm able to find actionscript in all keyframes. Furthermore, I've noticed that the "Actions - Frame" window shows me a tree of all the ActionScript in the scene, organized by frame. This isn't happening in the first .fla file - I can open up and edit actionscript for a frame, but the tree/index never gets built.

Has anyone run into a situation like this? Is the first .fla corrupt in some way, or is there a setting to allow me to easily find actionscript within all frames? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the settings in the search box? Maybe the search is document based and the specific file you are having trouble with has different settings from the default one. Try to compare the working file with your "corrupt" file. Actionsctipt should be enabled.

[image]